Problems with XC8 and PIC18 compiler: Soft stops working for no apparent reason
I'm facing a very annoying problem and would like to know if others have already encountered it.
I use PIC18F26K42, MPLAB 6.20, XC8 v2.50.
The problem is that, with the code working, sometimes I add a line and then it behaves strangely. It stops working.
To give you an idea, the code below is what works:
void exeCMD(void){
    if(!serial.flags.endCmd) return;
    serial.flags.endCmd = 0;
    serial.flags.startCmd = 0;
    switch(serial.cmd){
        case CMD_STATUS:    //---------------------------------------------- 
            if(serial.request == REQ_WRITE){

            }
            else if(serial.request == REQ_READ){
                serial.value = (ulong)((uint)status.cfg.value + (((uint)status.op.value) << 8));
                sendCMD(serial.cmd,serial.value);
            }
            break;

        case CMD_GET_TIME:   //---------------------------------------------- 
             if(serial.request == REQ_READ) {
                 serial.value = getSysTick(); // Nao é isso...
                 sendCMD(serial.cmd,serial.value);
             }
             else serial.value = 0;
             break;

        case CMD_GET_FREQ:   //---------------------------------------------- 
             if(serial.request == REQ_READ) {
                 getFreq();
                 serial.value = (ulong)freq.atual;
                 sendCMD(serial.cmd, serial.value);
             }       
             else 
                 serial.value = 0;
             break;

And this one stops working when I add some lines:
ulong delayTime[2];

void exeCMD(void){
    if(!serial.flags.endCmd) return;
    serial.flags.endCmd = 0;
    serial.flags.startCmd = 0;

    switch(serial.cmd){
        case CMD_STATUS:    //---------------------------------------------- 
             if(serial.request == REQ_WRITE){
             }
             else if(serial.request == REQ_READ){
                 serial.value = (ulong)((uint)status.cfg.value + (((uint)status.op.value) << 8));
                 sendCMD(serial.cmd,serial.value);
             }
             break;

        case CMD_GET_TIME:   //---------------------------------------------- 
             if(serial.request == REQ_READ) {
                 serial.value = getSysTick(); // Nao é isso...
                 sendCMD(serial.cmd,serial.value);
              }
              else serial.value = 0;
              break;

         case CMD_GET_FREQ:   //---------------------------------------------- 
              if(serial.request == REQ_READ) {
                  delayTime[0] = getSysTick();
                  getFreq();
                  delayTime[1] = getSysTick();
                  serial.value = (ulong)freq.atual;
                  sendCMD(serial.cmd, serial.value);
                  delayTime[1] = delayTime[1] - delayTime[0];
                  printStrNum( "T:",delayTime[1]);
              }
              else 
                  serial.value = 0;
              break;

I make it clear that the functions are implemented in several other parts of the code and are not the problem.
The interruptions do not call other functions and are short and simple codes.
The complete code has many lines. This is a part where I had this problem.
But this behavior is not limited to this region. Several times I have the code working and after a line is added it stops working.
The behavior changes. Sometimes it changes the value of a variable or writes meaningless strings.
I was using printf, but since I came across this problem, I thought it was the reason.
I also used C99, C90, C89... It all gives the same problem.
I really don't know what the problem is. I think it's either the XC2.50 compiler or MPLAB 6.20.

Where do you add which lines of code?
